# Not able to return value in django templetes using class-based view

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django and I don't know much about class-based view. I was trying to return value in Django template and  I am not able to access those value using template tag.I was trying to print value of distance and duration which you can see in my chart.html code.
 **Here is my views.py code**

```
class chartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'chart.html'

    def calculate(self):
        self.res=requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/')
        self.data=self.res.json()
        self.current_loc=self.data['city']
        gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='****************************') 
        my_dist = gmaps.distance_matrix(self.current_loc,'bhaktapur')['rows'][0]['elements'][0] 
        # Printing the result 
        #the variable name describes the distance and time for that bloodbank eg:-redcross,whitecross etc.
        redcross={
        'distance':my_dist['distance']['text'],
        'duration':my_dist['duration']['text']
        }
        my_dist = gmaps.distance_matrix(self.current_loc,'lalitpur')['rows'][0]['elements'][0] 
        whitecross={
        'distance':my_dist['distance']['text'],
        'duration':my_dist['duration']['text']
        }    
        my_dist = gmaps.distance_matrix(self.current_loc,'jorpati')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]     
        greencross={
        'distance':my_dist['distance']['text'],
        'duration':my_dist['duration']['text']
        }      
        my_dist = gmaps.distance_matrix(self.current_loc,'maharajgunj')['rows'][0]['elements'][0] 
        yellowcross={
        'distance':my_dist['distance']['text'],
        'duration':my_dist['duration']['text']
        }
        dist_list=[redcross,whitecross,greencross,yellowcross]

        return render(request,'chart.html',{'dist_list': dist_list})


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context  = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["qs"]= app.objects.all()
        return context
```

**my url.py code**

```
urlpatterns = [

    re_path(r'chart.html/$',views.chartView.as_view(),name="Charts"),
] 
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**chart.html code**

```
{% for items in qs %}
<div class="conty">
    <canvas class="myChart"></canvas>

</div><br><br>
<div align="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>{{items.name}}</th>
            <th>{{dist_list[0]['distance']}}</th>
            <th>{{dist_list[0]['duration']}}</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

**and my error is**

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[0]['duration']' from 'dist_list[0]['duration']'
[19/Feb/2020 00:32:22] "GET /chart.html/ HTTP/1.1" 500 159883
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <th>{{dist_list[0]['duration']}}</th>
```

or

```
        <th>{{dist_list[0].get('duration')}}</th>
```

instead of

```
        <th>{{dist_list[0][duration]}}</th>
```

---

Also replace the `calculate` function as following:

```
class ChartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'chart.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context  = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["qs"]= app.objects.all()

        res=requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/')
        data=self.res.json()
        current_loc=self.data['city']
        gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='****************************') 
        my_dist = gmaps.distance_matrix(self.current_loc,'bhaktapur')['rows'][0]['elements'][0] 
        # Printing the result 
        #the variable name describes the distance and time for that bloodbank eg:-redcross,whitecross etc.
        redcross={
        'distance':my_dist['distance']['text'],
        'duration':my_dist['duration']['text']
        }
        my_dist = gmaps.distance_matrix(self.current_loc,'lalitpur')['rows'][0]['elements'][0] 
        whitecross={
        'distance':my_dist['distance']['text'],
        'duration':my_dist['duration']['text']
        }    
        my_dist = gmaps.distance_matrix(self.current_loc,'jorpati')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]     
        greencross={
        'distance':my_dist['distance']['text'],
        'duration':my_dist['duration']['text']
        }      
        my_dist = gmaps.distance_matrix(self.current_loc,'maharajgunj')['rows'][0]['elements'][0] 
        yellowcross={
        'distance':my_dist['distance']['text'],
        'duration':my_dist['duration']['text']
        }
        dist_list=[redcross,whitecross,greencross,yellowcross]
        context['dist_list'] = dist_list
        return context
```

Comment: Is my function in views.py returning the value from ```def calculate(self)```?